# Angular 2 Http Service Injectable

Tags: http, service, angular, injectable

I'm pulling a big object from my server using Angular 2 service when the website starts. The data I need to pull looks like this:

```
{
    Edu: [...],
    Exp: [...],
    Links: [...],
    Portfolio: [...],
    Skills: [...]
}
```

And I set up the service this way:

AllDataService:

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class AllDataService {
  private allDataUrl = ".../allData";
  private loading: boolean;
  private Edu: Array<any>;
  private Exp: Array<any>;
  private Links: Array<any>;
  private Portfolio: Array<any>;
  private Skills: Array<any>;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.Edu = [];
    this.Exp = [];
    this.Links = [];
    this.Portfolio = [];
    this.Skills = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllData();
  }

  // Get data from api, aka "Set" methods
  getAllData() {
    return this.http.get(this.allDataUrl)
             .subscribe(
               data => {
                this.Edu = data.Edu;
                this.Exp = data.Exp;
                this.Links = data.Links;
                this.Portfolio = data.Portfolio;
                this.Skills = data.Skills;
                this.loading = false;
              },
               err => console.error(err)
             );
  }

  // “Get” methods
  getLoading() { return this.loading; }
  getEdu() { return this.Edu; }
  getExp() { return this.Exp; }
  getLinks() { return this.Links; }
  getPortfolio() { return this.Portfolio; }
  getSkills() { return this.Skills; }
}
```

And in my component, I inject the service so that I can get data:

HomeIcons:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { AllDataService } from "../allDataService";

@Component({
  selector: "home-icons",
  template: `
            <div class="home-icons-wrapper">
              <ul class="home-icons-ul no-select">
                <li class="home-icons-li"
                *ngFor="let link of links" >
                  <a href={{link.url}} target="_blank">
                    <span class="home-icons-icon {{link.icon}}"></span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            `,
  providers: [AllDataService]
})

export class HomeIcons {
  public links;

  constructor(private http: Http, private allDataService: AllDataService) {
    this.links = allDataService.getLinks();
  }
}
```

However, in the AllDataService, the error message tells me that properties (Exp, Edu, Skills...) don't exist in Response. How should I setup my http service correctly so that I can pull the data I want at start and make sure all the components get the data? Thanks

Comment: Could you please post your JSON data? And did you implement the `ToJson` method?

Comment: Can you show code of ToJson method. Is the error is compile time?

Comment: It was my bad to include the ToJson(), it's just a try, ignore it, I took it out of my code already.

Comment: Please paste the summary of error. Your code looks fine. As per your code Functions can return undefined/null value but function cannot be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do, is to convert your response to a JavaScript object:

```ts
// Get data from api, aka "Set" methods
getAllData() {
  return this.http.get(this.allDataUrl)
           .map(res => res.json()) // <-- this line here
           .subscribe(
             data => {
               this.Edu = data.Edu;
               this.Exp = data.Exp;
               this.Links = data.Links;
               this.Portfolio = data.Portfolio;
               this.Skills = data.Skills;
               this.loading = false;
             },
             err => console.error(err)
           );
}
```

Bind to the method directly in your template:

```
template: `
        <div class="home-icons-wrapper">
          <ul class="home-icons-ul no-select">
            <li class="home-icons-li"
            *ngFor="let link of allDataService.getLinks()" >
              <a href={{link.url}} target="_blank">
                <span class="home-icons-icon {{link.icon}}"></span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        `,
```

Comment: The error did go away, but I'm still not getting data, any ideas?

Comment: Yes, HTTP requests are running async in JavaScript. So the constructor of your component runs before the HTTP request finishes, thats why you get the empty array.

Comment: You can however bind directly to your service method instead of making a shallow copy. I updated my answer.

Comment: It's still not updating, would it be because the data is updated on the object but it's not updating the DOM?

Comment: You could try making the variable `private Links: Array<any>;` public and bind directly to it instead of the function call.

Comment: Still not working. I've put a console.log() inside the http.get().subscribe(), it not only doesn't log me anything, but also it doesn't return any error to me... I'm pretty sure my link for the get method works because I can see the data on the browser. So I'm thinking the method isn't used at all